# How can I read all the values from this array of arrays in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Community,

I want to read all the values from this json. I am using C#. How do I manage do that? I am trying to use the openroute service distance matrix.
My Idea:

```
 string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var jobject = JObject.Parse(responseData);
 var onlydistance = jobject.SelectTokens("$.distances[*]")
   .Values<double>()
   .ToArray();
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "distances": [[0, 108628.26, 2669713, 11595025], [108952.97, 0, 2674477.75, 11609762], [2688555, 2681139.5, 0, 8405009], [11596626, 11611808, 8734262, 0]],
    "destinations": [
        {
            "location": [9.700817, 48.476406],
            "snapped_distance": 118.92
        },
        {
            "location": [9.207773, 49.153882],
            "snapped_distance": 10.54
        },
        {
            "location": [37.572963, 55.801279],
            "snapped_distance": 17.45
        },
        {
            "location": [115.665017, 38.100717],
            "snapped_distance": 648.79
        }
    ],
    "sources": [
        {
            "location": [9.700817, 48.476406],
            "snapped_distance": 118.92
        },
        {
            "location": [9.207773, 49.153882],
            "snapped_distance": 10.54
        },
        {
            "location": [37.572963, 55.801279],
            "snapped_distance": 17.45
        },
        {
            "location": [115.665017, 38.100717],
            "snapped_distance": 648.79
        }
    ],
    "metadata":
    {
        "attribution": "openrouteservice.org | OpenStreetMap contributors",
        "service": "matrix",
        "timestamp": 1603348601609,
        "query":
        {
            "locations": [[9.70093, 48.477473], [9.207916, 49.153868], [37.573242, 55.801281], [115.663757, 38.106467]],
            "profile": "cycling-road",
            "responseType": "json",
            "metricsStrings": ["DISTANCE"],
            "metrics": ["distance"],
            "units": "m"
        },
        "engine":
        {
            "version": "6.3.0",
            "build_date": "2020-10-19T02:01:48Z",
            "graph_date": "2020-10-12T06:58:07Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "save" isn't the best word. You seemingly want to extract all of the values from the arrays in the distances array.

Comment: Please add your JSON to the question as text rather than as an image - BTW that's not JSON.

Comment: Have you tried your idea? did it work? what didn't work?

Comment: Can you also answer Liam's questions, please?

Comment: Why don't you populate class model from your JSON and do whatever you want with it?Something like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModelClass>(responseData);

Comment: That could be something like: `var distances = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<double[]>>(jobject["distances"].ToString());`. But, as mentioned, you're probably better off writing your class structure/model to deserialize that JSON, much handier.

Comment: extending on previous comments of creating your own model, [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has an extension called [paste json as code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype) which basically does all the work for you when creating models from json

Comment: @Jochem Van Hespen Don't suggest that :) It works only with very simple structures. e.g., [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) is much better.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the suggestion but the vs code extension is by quicktype, and the site your mentioning is called quicktype so aint it just the same thing?

Comment: @Jochem Van Hespen Well, I read your comment only partially: there's often someone that suggests to use Visual Studio's `Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes`. I was referring to this tool. I'm not sure the Visual Studio Code suggestion applies here.

Comment: hmm I see, well anyway didn't know quicktype had a webapplication so much thanks for pointing that out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator/converter to generate Json Classes eg: https://json2csharp.com/

Sample code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\root\t01.json");
    Root root  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonData);
}

public class Root    {
    public List<List<double>> distances { get; set; } 
    public List<Destination> destinations { get; set; } 
    public List<Source> sources { get; set; } 
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; } 
}

public class Destination    {
    public List<double> location { get; set; } 
    public double snapped_distance { get; set; } 
}

public class Source    {
    public List<double> location { get; set; } 
    public double snapped_distance { get; set; } 
}

public class Query    {
    public List<List<double>> locations { get; set; } 
    public string profile { get; set; } 
    public string responseType { get; set; } 
    public List<string> metricsStrings { get; set; } 
    public List<string> metrics { get; set; } 
    public string units { get; set; } 
}

public class Engine    {
    public string version { get; set; } 
    public DateTime build_date { get; set; } 
    public DateTime graph_date { get; set; } 
}

public class Metadata    {
    public string attribution { get; set; } 
    public string service { get; set; } 
    public long timestamp { get; set; } 
    public Query query { get; set; } 
    public Engine engine { get; set; } 
}
```